# create cart and add line items using connect API for commerce cloud

Tags: apex, connect-api

I tried to create cart using ConnectApi.createCart but this is showing error that

> Variable does not exist: ConnectApi

The above issue is getting when in tried from developer console. Do anyone have any idea or have you implemented this scenario.

```
ConnectApi.CartInput cart = new ConnectApi.CartInput();
ConnectApi.CartSummary  cartSummary =ConnectApi.createCart('store Id',cart);
```

Do anyone here help me out if you have tried anything like this.

Comment: Don't you need to include the [specific class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_CommerceCart_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_CommerceCart_static_methods), like `ConnectApi.CommerceCart.createCart()`?  But I have not used Commerce Cloud so I am just guessing.